# VSTS internal feed package restore error on VS2015: array must contain atleast one element

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I have published a simple NuGet package containing 4 .cs files on VSTS and download and install it successfully from VSTS Internal NuGet feed. While trying to update or uninstall the package, I get the error : "The array must contain at least one element". If I delete the classes manually and packages.config and then install the package freshly again, it succeeds but the Update/Uninstall fails always.

This happens when I install/update/uninstall the package on a project connected to VSTS. Even on checking out the complete project causes this issue. VS displays an error message : "The package at 'D:\TestPath..\PackageName.1.0.0.1.' failed to uninstall. Restart Visual Studio to finish the process". However, the package gets uninstalled/updated successfully. On a standalone project not connected to VSTS, the package gets installed/updated/uninstalled successfully.

How can I prevent such error for a project connected to VSTS from appearing while installing/updating/uninstalling the package from a internal VSTS package feed url.

The .nuspec file is as below:

[image: NuSpec file pic attached]

Answer (score 0):

We can reproduce this issue with the latest NuGet Packager Manager version  3.5.0.1996 ,not on previous version 3.5.0.1848, so please check your NuGet Packager Manager version.

We have reported this issue on NuGet Gallery, please refer to [Issue 3459](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/3459) for detail.

Before this issue resolved, you can check in entire project with the installed package before update/uninstall the package to prevent such error for a project connected to VSTS.

Comment: Do you have tried check in entire project? It works fine in my side when I check in entire project into VSTS.

Comment: Yes, I have tried by checking-in and checking-out the entire project is checked/unchecked in VSTS. When I use Visual Studio 2015. When I go to Tools -> Extensions and Updates and search for NuGet Package Manager, I see the installed version as 3.4.4.1321. There is no message to update the NuGet Package Manager, so I believe that the latest version for Visual Studio 2015 is installed. Both in Visual Studio 2015 Professional and Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise RC, I face the same issue as mentioned in my post.